# get global. variable inside ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

result is undefined why? how to solve this problem. assign variable and i need to use that variable before

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getAdvanceAmount (element, callback) {
  if (element === '' || !window.XMLHttpRequest) return

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.responseText)
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', 'get_advance_amount.php?q=' + element, true)
  xhr.send()
    }

function get_value()
{
    getAdvanceAmount('1',function (karat) {
        console.log(karat)
        k1=karat;
    })
    alert(k1);
}
</script>
<button onclick="get_value()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous request, so it will take sometime to finish, and call your callback function.

On the other hand, you are calling `alert` immediately after `click` event firing, so the callback is not fired yet, and assigned the `karat` to `k1` variable.

```
getAdvanceAmount('1',function (karat) {
    console.log(karat)
    useKaratValue(karat);
})

function useKaratValue(karat) {
    // Make use of the value here...
}
```

This will solve the issue, and alert after getting `karat` value.

Comment: so no solution. any other way to get data from database and use at javascript

Comment: @DerickChooty You can use it, but you have to wait until you get the value, so inside the callback add your code that uses the value, see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It would work fine, if you change your as follows:

Your Code:

```
function get_value()
{
    getAdvanceAmount('1',function (karat) {
        console.log(karat)
        k1=karat;
    })
    alert(k1);
}
```

Change it as follows:

```
function get_value()
{
    getAdvanceAmount('1',function (karat) {
        console.log(karat)
        alert(karat);
    })
}
```

Since this is async call your alerting code should also be in the callback function.

For better crossbrowser compatibility, not only with IE6/7, but also to cover some browser-specific memory leaks or bugs, and also for less verbosity with firing ajaxical requests, you could use jQuery.

```
$.get('get_advance_amount.php?q=' + element, function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I know this but i need to use that variable outside of Funtion or other funtion

Comment: In an asynchronous request, before it come to the callback function rest of the function will be executed. In JavaScript it doesn't interrupt current execution and callback has to wait till it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `getAdvanceAmount` function and you pass some parameters to it, namely an element and a function called `callback`. `getAdvanceAmount` sends an AJAX request and when it receives a response, executes the `callback`. Inside the `callback` `k1` is initialized.

After `getAdvanceAmount` is executed, there is an attempt to use `k1`, however, it is unsuccessful. The reason is that the `callback` was not executed yet by the time `k1`'s value is tried to be used. This is what happens:

- `getAdvanceAmount` is called
- an AJAX request is sent
- `k1`'s value is attempted to be used
- the server receives the request
- the server parses the request
- the server sends the response
- the browser receives the response
- the browser calls the `callback` which initializes `k1`

You simply tried to use `k1`'s value chronologically before it was initialized, due to the mistaken assumption that using it after calling `getAdvanceAmount`, which is responsible for its initialization guarantees that it will be initialized, which is clearly not the case. Try to use `k1` in the `callback` and you will see it was properly initialized.